# How to continue polling with observable interval if error occurs

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

I have a simple network polling function with observable intervals

```
private fun pollFromApi(): Observable<MyState> {
    return Observable.interval(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, schedulerProvider.io())
        .startWith(0L)
        .flatMap {
            api.getState().toObservable()
        }
        .map {
            // map response to MyState
        }
        .onErrorReturn {
            return@onErrorReturn MyState.Polling // if error occurred emit Polling State
        }
        .takeUntil {
            // stop polling if certain State is reached
        }
}
```

The problem I have is that if in the middle of polling one of the network API calls fails, the polling stops. Ideally what I want is to keep retrying until `takeUntil` stops the polling and if an error occurs, just ignore it and do not emit anything to observers.

I tried adding `onErrorReturn` but that just catches the error and stops the polling.

Comment: Please post the code with that `onErrorReturn` you used.

Comment: @akarnokd updated. Basically just returned the Polling State. As I said, it catches the error but stops the interval polling

Comment: If `getState` fails, put `onErrorReturn` on `getState`.

Comment: In that case, I guess I need to return a raw network response which is much more complicated

Comment: is there any function to ignore the error somehow?

Comment: Do the mapping inside `flatMap` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observable#onErrorResumeNext` operator chained to your remote (possibly failing) API call, emitting an item that **does not meet your `#takeUntil` clause** to avoid stopping processing:

```
private fun pollFromApi(): Observable<MyState> {
    return Observable.interval(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, schedulerProvider.io())
        .startWith(0L)
        .flatMap {
            api.getState().toObservable().onErrorResumeNext(ignored -> null) // or some other SENTINEL value
        }
        .map {
            // map response to MyState
        }
        .takeUntil {
            // stop polling if certain State is reached
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you'll have to do the mapping and error handling on the api call itself inside the `flatMap`:

```kotlin
private fun pollFromApi(): Observable<MyState> {
    return Observable.interval(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, schedulerProvider.io())
        .startWith(0L)
        .flatMap {
            api.getState().toObservable()
            .map {
                // map response to MyState
            }
            .onErrorReturn {
                return@onErrorReturn MyState.Polling // if error occurred emit Polling State
            }
        }
        .takeUntil {
            // stop polling if certain State is reached
        }
}
```